# Getting widths of dynamic float divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a dynamic dropdown navigation.

In the dropdown there are multiple floating divs, but between each 'row of items' I have to add a horizontal divider. I can't set a static width because the text-length of the items are dynamic and may not wrap.

So I am reading each container, reading all div items, I want to read the width of the items to add the divider but can't manage it.

```
$('.muTopNavDropdown').each(function(i, e) {
        var iWidth = 0;
        $(this).find('.mainSubNavRowItem').each(function(ii, ee) {
        if (iWidth > maxWidth)
        alert('divide!');

            alert($(ee).width() +'-'+ $(ee).offsetWidth +'-'+ $(ee).clientWidth);

            iWidth += $(ee).width();
        });

    });
```

How do I read a floating div with no width value and dynamic content inside **width**?

Comment: From the sounds of it, you don't need anything so complicated. Can't you just have a `display: block; margin:0 10px` divider?

Comment: Believe me, clients are always the smartest and complicated people known to developers.

Comment: Can you show what you have so far using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It will help get your actual question answered, and it will help me to see if there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Teos answered my question. It was display:none on initial load. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. Are your divs visible?
If divs are set to display none jquery will not be able to return a width.

Comment: 100%! Thanks dude. I set display:none to block and widths were reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

innerWidth() should do what your after